# Atraso antes de mostrar um div

Tags: html, css

Ok, não estou a perceber o que me esta a falhar.

A minha ideia era quando passar com o rato em cima de uma div, mostrar a div que estava escondida.

```css
.main_container:hover .hidden_container
{
  display: block;
}

.hidden_container
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="main_container">
  <p>On hover here</p>
  <div class="hidden_container">
    <p>Shows this</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Estou a tentar criar um "delay" para não mostrar a div "hidden-container" instantaneamente.

O que não estou a conseguir é criar o atraso de 1 seg. antes de mostrar a div. Já vi o `transition-delay: 1seg;` mas não estou a conseguir o que quero.

O perfeito era fazer isto em HTML + CSS. Mas se JS resolver o problema, aceitarei como solução.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `display` é uma propriedade que não permite animação, ou o campo é visível ou não, portante não é possível usar o `display` com o `delay`.

[Animatable CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)

Como alternativa você pode usar a propriedade `opacity`:

```css
.main_container:hover .hidden_container
{
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.hidden_container
{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_container">
  <p>Passe o mouse aqui.</p>
  <div class="hidden_container">
    <p>Exibido após 1 segundo.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do Caique é válida, você também pode utilizar o transition trabalhando com cores, assim o seu hover fica mais agradável e não aparece para o usuário de forma "agressiva".

```css
.main_container:hover .hidden_container
{
  color: black;
  transition: color 1s;
  
  
}

.hidden_container
{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_container">
  <p>Passe o mouse aqui.</p>
  <div class="hidden_container">
    <p>Exibido após 1 segundo.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando JavaScript você pode pegar os dois eventos (`mouseover` e `mouseleave`) e com um `setTimeout` no `mouseover` construir o mesmo efeito:

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll(".main_container > p"); // seleciono todos os <p> filhos
var atraso; // declaro a variável que servirá com temporizador
for(x=0; x<els.length; x++){
   els[x].onmouseover = function(){
      var el = this; // <p> que chamou o evento
      atraso = setTimeout(function(){
         el.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block'; // mostra a div que vem após o <p>
      }, 1000);
   }

   els[x].onmouseleave = function(){
      clearTimeout(atraso); // cancelo o temporizador
      this.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none'; // esconde a div que vem após o <p>
   }
}
```

```css
.hidden_container
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_container">
  <p>On hover here</p>
  <div class="hidden_container">
    <p>Shows this1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main_container">
  <p>On hover here</p>
  <div class="hidden_container">
    <p>Shows this2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```